# List all pages containing shortcode (WordPress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am writing a plugin for wordpress that creates shortcodes. On this plugins settings page, I would like to have it list out what pages the shortcode is being used on. (For ease of access and locating them for quick changes.)

I figured it would be something with get_post(), where it searched all the posts that matched a filter, then listed them, but I can't seem to figure out what the syntax for that would be, or if this is even possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: although you can drop a hook in that notifies you when your shortcode is being called/parsed, that would still rely on every page being loaded. You're going to have to do a DB query for sure. you can use get posts, loop through all posts, and then use `strpos`  on appropriate field(s) (content, custom metaboxes etc) 
alternatively you can query the DB directly: `SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_value` LIKE '%[hello]%' LIMIT 0,1000`;
this will give you the result set including post_ids

Comment: Loop throught all posts is not so good idea. Just make a hook on post save/update and check if this post used your shortcode, or not. If use — place post id to new custom table and just get all records from your custom table.

Comment: i disagree, this requires all posts to have been loaded at least once for registration to take place. i.e. when you first install and activate your plugin that list will be incomplete. you could minimize unnecessary queries by only doing your query/loop  on plugin install (and then adding those records to a custom table as amedv suggests) or you could wrap said query in a transient cache

Comment: Working on implementing a system using the query: SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%[mod-%' AND `post_status` = 'publish' LIMIT 0,1000
based off of @baku 's comment. Will post results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured this out with help from the wordpress forums.

Managed to do it like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT ID, post_title, guid FROM ".$wpdb->posts." WHERE post_content LIKE '%[mod-%' AND post_status = 'publish'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results ($query);
```

Then displayed it like so:

```
<?php foreach ( $results as $results ) { ?><p><a>ID;?>"><?php echo $results->post_title;?></a><br></p><?php } ?>
```

This will list all pages containing "[mod-" and provide a link to them.

Answer (score 0):

I've put it in a handy shortcode :)

Please note: this filters for some post status' only.

```
add_shortcode('find_posts_with_shortcode', function ($atts = []) {
    $atts = wp_parse_args($atts, [
        'tag' => false,
    ]);

    if (!$atts['tag']) {
        return __('"tag" parameter is required');
    }

    $tag = trim($atts['tag']);

    // Adapted from shortcodes.php#add_shortcode
    if (0 !== preg_match('@[<>&/\[\]\x00-\x20=]@', $tag)) {
        /* translators: 1: Shortcode name, 2: Space-separated list of reserved characters. */
        return sprintf(__('Invalid shortcode name: %1$s. Do not use spaces or reserved characters: %2$s'), $tag, '& / < > [ ] =');
    }

    global $wpdb;
    $query = $wpdb->prepare(
         "SELECT id, post_title, post_status
                 FROM  $wpdb->posts
                 WHERE (post_content LIKE %s OR post_content LIKE %s)
                 AND post_status IN ('publish', 'private', 'draft') 
                 ORDER BY post_title",
        '%[' . $wpdb->esc_like($tag) . ' %', // i.e. [tag param..]
        '%[' . $wpdb->esc_like($tag) . ']%' // i.e. [tag]
    );

    $shortcode_usages = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    if (count($shortcode_usages) == 0) {
        return __('No usage found');
    }

    ob_start();
    foreach ($shortcode_usages as $post) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->id) . '">' . $post->post_title . ' (' . $post->post_status . ')</a><br />';
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
});
```